# Select2 Custom Tags, Transform Value on Select

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I would like a dropdown of text and then when one is selected I would like to load the full value as the tag and have it behave as normal.

I'm capturing the values selected then clearing the list and appending them as text into the `.select2-choices` div. It appears to work as it should but I've lost the ability to **clear** the manually appended tags.

**Markup:**

```
<div id="select2-container">
    <select multiple class="select2" id="select2">
        <optgroup label="GroupName">
            <option value="John Smith - GroupName (ID:12345678)">John Smith</option>
        </optgroup>
    </select>
</div>
```

**Script:**

```
$('#select2').select2({               
    }).on('change', function (e) {
        values = $(this).val();
        console.log(values);
        $('#select2-container .select2-choices').empty();
        for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            console.log(values[i]);
            $('#select2-container .select2-choices').append('<li class="select2-search-choice"><div>' + values[i] + '</div><a href="#" class="select2-search-choice-close" tabindex="-1"></a></li>');
        }
    });
```

I'm going to look into the formatSelection function but any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've probably solved this by now, but you are correct that you want to use `formatSelection`.

Be default, the selected object's `text` property is used, but you want the `id` property instead. The `id` property is the `<option>` element's value.

```
$('#select2').select2({
    formatSelection: function(object) {
        return object.id;
    }
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uynqof4z/1/)

Comment: Thanks John, this works perfectly and is much cleaner than listening to change and manually transforming.

Comment: For anyone that stumble over this answer and wonder why it doesn't work, select2 change the name of the option from `formatSelection` to `templateSelection`.

Answer (score -1):

This is a solution in my project:

In edit.php file:

**solution 1 (cate id is single number):**

```
<?php
    $cate_row = $db->fetchRow("SELECT cate_id, cate_name FROM categories WHERE cate_id=".$editdata[cate_id]." AND cate_status='Active'");
    $cateArray[] = array("id"=>$cate_row['cate_id'], "text"=>$cate_row['cate_id']." - ".$cate_row['cate_name']);

    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
        AjaxCombo('#categories', '/ajax/getCategories.php', true)
    </script>";

    echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"sl2\" id=\"categories\" value='".json_encode($cateArray)."' data-placeholder=\"Select a category for this product..\" style=\"width: 400px !important;\" />";
?>
```

**solution 2 (cate id is array: 12,4,5,6 or ,12,4,5,6,):**

```
<?php
    $cate_q = $db->query("SELECT cate_id, cate_name FROM categories WHERE cate_status='Active' ORDER BY cate_name ASC");

    // array: ,12,4,5,6,
    $editcate_array = explode(",", substr($editdata[cate_id], 1, $editdata[cate_id] - 1));
    // or array 12,4,5,6
    // $editcate_array = explode(",", $editdata[cate_id]);

    while($cate_row = $db->fetch_array($cate_q)){
        if(in_array($row['cate_id'], $editcate_array)) {
            $cateArray[] = array("id"=>$cate_row['cate_id'], "text"=>$cate_row['cate_id']." - ".$cate_row['cate_name']);
        }
    }

    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
        AjaxCombo('#categories', '/ajax/getCategories.php', true)
    </script>";

    echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"sl2\" id=\"categories\" value='".json_encode($cateArray)."' data-placeholder=\"Select a category for this product..\" style=\"width: 400px !important;\" />";
?>
```

In JS global.js:

```
function AjaxCombo(elm, url, multiple) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(elm).select2({
            multiple: multiple,
            minimumInputLength: 1,
            ajax: {
                url: url,
                dataType: 'json',
                quietMillis: 100,
                data: function (term, page) {
                    return { q: term };
                },
                results: function (data, page) {
                    return {results: data};
                }
            },
            // Add new category if no exist
            createSearchChoice:function(term, data) { if ($(data).filter(function() { return this.text.localeCompare(term)===0; }).length===0) {return {id:term, text:term};} }
        });
        $(elm).select2("data", JSON.parse($(elm).val()));
    });
}
```

Default if form edit have cate data select2 init "id - Name category".

in file getCategories.php : from select you get `$q = $input->gc['q']` and mysql is `cate_name LIKE '%" . $q . "%';`

```
while($row = $db->fetch_array($result)){
    $dataArray[] = array("id"=>$row['cate_id'], "text"=>$row['cate_id']." - ".$row['cate_name']);
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($answer);
```

when get value form select2 you can try:

```
foreach ($_GET['select2'] as $value) {
    echo $value;
}
```

done!

Comment: How does this answer the question?